# Has there been a decrease of US aid to Iraq under Trump?

Tags: united-states, iraq, foreign-aid

Trump has recently [threatened](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-51003159) Iraq with sanctions if they decide to expel US troops.

His statement didn't explicitly say anything about [withdrawing] US aid, which [appears](https://www.propublica.org/article/the-trump-administration-gutted-the-staff-overseeing-1-billion-in-aid-to-iraq-a-watchdog-is-raising-red-flags) to still be ongoing, despite some personnel reductions. As Trump has been said (at least in the impeachment hearings) to be generally skeptical of US foreign aid, I'm curious: has there been a decrease in US aid to Iraq under the Trump administration, compared to the previous administration(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the United States Agency for International Development (USAID), funding has decreased under the Trump administration.

Much of this decrease appears to be lowering aid values following a large spike in 2015/2016, and values for 2018/2019 are not fully reported/processed yet so the actual amounts are not yet known.

Select data taken from [USAID's page on U.S. Foreign Aid by Country for Iraq](https://explorer.usaid.gov/cd/IRQ?fiscal_year=2017&measure=Obligations):

```
Year    Amount (dollars)   Notes
2002        1,039,000      Pre-invasion
2003    3,849,469,396      Invasion year
...
2006    9,674,914,001      Highest value overall
...
2009    5,694,815,040
...
2013      445,885,569
2014      414,729,876      Post-invasion low point
2015    1,547,616,372
2016    5,281,583,316      Highest since 2009
2017    3,711,900,430
2018    1,481,722,677      Not fully reported yet*
2019       82,018,707      Not fully reported yet*
```

[image: Graph of US aid to Iraq, showing high in 2009, low in 2014, rise in 2016]

> *According to [USAID](https://explorer.usaid.gov/about#tab-status): There is a two year lag for the most recent complete year of data. This lag exists because foreign assistance data collection and reporting is approximately a year-long process from when the fiscal year ends.